# post not showing on Facebook page wall - Swit 4

Tags: swift

I'm trying to upload a post on a Facebook business page wall using graph API (page_id/photos) and SWIFT 4 in iOS, but after response when I see Facebook page my post will show in visitor post instead of Facebook page wall. I try to pass page access token ad parameter and give manage_pages, publish_pages and publish_action but still post is showing in visitor post. Please help me out.

```
 let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
            connection.add(FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "/\(pageId)?fields=access_token", parameters: nil)) { (httpResponse, result, error) in

                if let error = error {
                   // print("Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    let result = result as! [String:Any]
                    self.pageAccessToken = result["access_token"] as! String
                }
              }
            connection.start()

            let params = [
                "access_token":self.pageAccessToken,
                "caption":self.itemName.text! + " - $ " + self.itemcost + " " + self.width + "w x " + self.depth + "d x " + self.height + "h",
                "url":imageURL,
                "appId":FBSDKAccessToken.current().appID,
                "uid":FBSDKAccessToken.current().userID]

            FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "\(pageId)/photos", parameters: params, httpMethod: "POST").start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Success")
                    print(result)
}
```